# Child processes in bash

Tags: linux, bash

We use bash scripts with asynchonous calls using '&'. Something like this:

```
function test() {
   sleep 1
} 
test &
mypid=$!
# do some stuff for two hours
wait $mypid
```

Usually everything is OK, but sometimes we get error

```
"wait: pid 419090 is not a child of this shell"
```

I know that bash keeps child pids in a special table and I know ('man wait') that bash is allowed not to store status information in this table if nobody uses $!, and nobody can state 'wait $mypid'. I suspect, that this optimization contains a bug that causes the error. Does somebody know how to print this table or how to disable this optimization?

Comment: What if the PID was reused by a different process?

Comment: @choroba Shouldn't matter, because bash should still store it in an internal table.

Comment: Perhaps somewhere else you're issuing an argument-less `wait`?

Comment: Except `wait(2)` take only an integer, not a unique handle. If, as @choroba suggests, the PID has been reused, then the kernel will respond with ECHILD because the PID *is not* a child of the shell.

Comment: @msw Bash's `wait` does a lot more than simply calling `wait(2)`.

Comment: So with the above script you can reproduce the problem ?

Comment: @msw: Bash's `wait` is not checking the process table. I assume SIGCHLD signals are services constantly - otherwise you would have a lot of processes in zombie state. However, there are small chances that *another* child will be spawn with the same PID as one of the previous children. In that case I guess only the first/last (?) child return code will be obtained, and second `wait` command will produce the error code shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying recently something quite similar. 
Are you sure that the second process you run concurrently starts before the previous dies? In this case, I think that there is a possibility it takes the same pid with the recently died one.

Also I think we cannot be sure that $! takes the pid of the process we lastly run, because there may be several processes in the background from another functions starting or ending at the same time.

I would suggest using something like this.

```
mypid=$(ps -ef | grep name_of_your_process | awk ' !/grep/ {print $2} ')
```

In `grep name_of_your_process` you can specify some parameters too so as to get the exact process you want.

I hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Having written something similar, I suggest the correct strategy is to fork in background BOTH function test and the long running 2 hour stuff.

Then you can wait on a list of pids, invoked in background sorted by the expected running times (fastest first).

The bash(1) wait also allows you to simply wait, for all of the child processes to complete, but that may require a checking protocol for successful completions.

An alternative approach for greater reliability is to use batch queues, with a seperate process started to check for sucessful completions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gdb to attach to a running shell and see what's happening.  On my system I ran `yum install bash-debuginfo`.  I ran `gdb` and attached to a running shell.

```
(gdb) b wait_for_single_pid
Breakpoint 1 at 0x441840: file jobs.c, line 2115.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, wait_for_single_pid (pid=11298) at jobs.c:2115
2115    {
(gdb) n
2120      BLOCK_CHILD (set, oset);
(gdb)
2121      child = find_pipeline (pid, 0, (int *)NULL);
(gdb) s
find_pipeline (pid=pid@entry=11298, alive_only=alive_only@entry=0, jobp=jobp@entry=0x0) at jobs.c:1308
1308    {
(gdb)
1313      if (jobp)
(gdb) n
1315      if (the_pipeline)
(gdb)
1329      job = find_job (pid, alive_only, &p);
(gdb) s
find_job (pid=11298, alive_only=0, procp=procp@entry=0x7ffdc053f038) at jobs.c:1364
1364      for (i = 0; i < js.j_jobslots; i++)
(gdb) n
1372          if (jobs[i])
(gdb)
1374              p = jobs[i]->pipe;
(gdb)
1378                  if (p->pid == pid && ((alive_only == 0 && PRECYCLED(p) == 0) || PALIVE(p)))
(gdb)
1385                  p = p->next;
(gdb)
1387              while (p != jobs[i]->pipe);
```

There code is traversing the `pipe` linked lists attached to the `jobs` array.  I didn't encounter any bugs, but perhaps you can spot them with this approach.